# PL/SQL time diffrence

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I don't have any experience in PL/SQL but I think I need it.

I have the following problem:

I have a table which contains:

```
Object  Station Time
744          2  23:40:00
744          3  23:45:00
744          4  23:48:00
744          8  23:59:00
744          9  00:02:00
744          13 00:15:00
```

Now I need a new field with date:

```
Object  Station Time    Date
744          2  23:40:00    26.03.2013
744          3  23:45:00    26.03.2013
744          4  23:48:00    26.03.2013
744          8  23:59:00    26.03.2013
744          9  00:02:00    27.03.2013
744         13  00:15:00    27.03.2013
```

You can see that’s the date has been changed if the time has reached 00:00:00

In SQL I don’t have any idea how I could do this - so now I think I need a PL/SQL script to create the Date.

Comment: How do you know that the first row is on March 26, 2013?  How do you sort the table?  Do we need to parse the `Object` column which appears to be a `varchar2` composed of two numeric values?

Comment: Where does the date come from? Do you always want to use the current date as the base date?

Comment: the date should be generated automatically.
If the time is <23:59:00 trunc(sysdate-1) should be placed, else take sysdate.

what my idea was before:

I have to each station a time information and if the time information < as the time before set trunc(sysdate)

Comment: Are you aware of the `DATE` data type in Oracle?

Comment: In your sample data, all the times are `< 23:59:00`.  If we go by the logic you posted in your comment, there are only 59 seconds in the day where you would assign a date of `trunc(sysdate)`.  That doesn't seem to match with the sample data you posted and doesn't seem to make a great deal of logical sense.

Comment: Technically `If the time is <23:59:00 trunc(sysdate-1)` is 99,9% - and also 00:02:00 is also considered there, not to 27/03/2013 as you wwrote. Your citeria should be something like if 12:00:01<X<23:59:00 - then sysdate-1 , else sysdate. Consider this and tell what's the type of the `Time` column.

Comment: Do the dates start over at 26.03.1013 when you reach a new object?

Answer (score 0):

Since you neither state what datatypes the table is created with, nor what possible values the table can contain, nor why exactly the desired result should be produced, it's impossible to come up with a correct solution. But you might start with something like

```
create table tq84_t (
  station  number,
  time     varchar2(8)
);

insert into tq84_t values ( 2, '23:40:00');
insert into tq84_t values ( 3, '23:45:00');
insert into tq84_t values ( 4, '23:48:00');
insert into tq84_t values ( 8, '23:59:00');
insert into tq84_t values ( 9, '00:02:00');
insert into tq84_t values (13, '00:15:00');

select 
  station,
  time,
  to_char(trunc(sysdate) -1 +
         sum(next_day) over (order by station), 'dd.mm.yyyy') date_
from (
  select
     case when nvl(lag(time) over (order by station), chr(0)) < time 
          then 0 
          else 1 end next_day,
    time,
    station
  from
    tq84_t
)
order by 
  station;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
INSERT INTO #your_table
SELECT 744 as OBJECT, 13 as Station , '00:15:00' as your time , CONVERT(varchar ,  GETDATE(), 103)
```

^^ this will only work  if you insert current day values;

or you could simply do it with  DATETIME Field

```
CREATE TABLE #yortable 
(OBJECT INT, Station int ,  Arrival_date datetime )
```

for example you have bus station, it should arrive at '2013/03/28 23:30:00' and unf it  is late . you simply add  value to it

```
update #yortable 
set Arrival_date  = DATEADD(mi, 31, Arrival_date  ) 
WHERE Station=1 and object=744
```

mi- minute
hh - hour 
ss - second

result

> '2013/03/29 00:01:00'

Comment: That's not valid Oracle SQL

Comment: I have an object which have station’s with time information And if the next station time < as the station time before set sysdate else sysdate-1 But this I could only make with an PL/SQL script? the new field is a datetype